# Number of candidate inputs that can be handled by different modelling techniques

Tags: r, modeling, feature-selection

Am I correct if I say that some modelling techniques can handle better a larger number of candidate inputs? (If we hold the number of observation constant).

Let's say I put around 60 different variables for several models at once using the fscaret package in R. (Ex: Glm, Lasso, Ridge, rpart, RRFglobal)

Could it be that some models are "overwhelmed" by the number of variables more than others?

Comment: Your intuition makes sense. Feature selection can sometimes make a modelling tasks easier. Tree methods are sometimes seen as a reasonable way of selecting features. Tree methods (decision tree, random forest) evaluate each input variable as part of the tree building: it is built in in the method. More on this subject matter can be found for example here: http://www.ulb.ac.be/di/map/gbonte/bioinfo/course4.pdf